# Can't get MySQL to start

Tags: mysql, macos

I can't get my MySQL Sever to start. It had been running fine for a month or so since the install, but after a reboot yesterday, it will not start. I have tried a number of recommendations from other posts here, but no luck.

This install worked fine until the reboot. According to Activity Monitor I do have one mysqld process running.

I get this error from: 
mysql -u root
"ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)"

I get this error when running: 
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
"ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/laptop.pid)."

Also the MySQL prerPane shows the Server Status stopped. Clicking the "Start MySQL Server" brings the spinning ball and doesn't start the server.

I don't want to uninstall and reinstall.

I'm running 10.9.6 OSX and what seems to be mysql-5.6.22-osx10.8-x86_64. (even though I also have a directory for mysql-5.7.10-osx10.9-x86_64 in my /usr/local/ directory). My install is from the Pkg file from the MySQL website.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Since mysqld is already running and the pidfile is locked, just try accessing the database.  Or try: `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart`

Comment: restart command gives same error as start mysql

Comment: Maybe the running mysqld process is "orphaned" in that its pid doesn't match the pidfile, but it still is holding the network socket.  In the terminal you can use `ps -ef | grep mysqld` to get the process id, then `kill -9 <pid>` to kill it.  Sorry I'm not a OSX user, there's probably a GUI way to find and kill wayward processes.  But if mysqld is out there running and not responding, kill it one way or another and try to start is my advice.

Answer (score 0):

Card-carrying OS/X user here . . .

Start by firing up the `Console` utility and using it to examine the logs in `/var/log/apache2`.  (Use *File..Open..* within the utility.)

I'm a little bit uncomfortable about your actual boots-on-the-ground situation because you indicate that you have installed a version that is different from the one that Apple provides.  *(How did it work, before?)*  Apple's utilities can only be expected to know about Apple's expected tools.

*(Incidentally, the latest OS/X, "El Capitan," is running 5.7.**11** as "the official, Apple-installed version.")*

Comment: Not sure what to look for in the Apache2 logs. Did a search of Console for "mysgl". Searched Apache2 and found nothing, or at least I believe so.) Also, 10.9 OSX doesn't seem to come with MySQL.)

Comment: I can tell you quite definitively that MySQL *is* installed by default ("because I am *looking* at it ...!")  **:-D** Look, particularly, in the `error_log` file.  Also look carefully at the system-logs which *Console* displays in its default screen.  I can't necessarily tell you what to look for, but, "you'll know it when you see it."

Comment: *(face-palm)* **D'oh!** Of course, I am utterly wrong:  I *did* install MySQL separately on this machine.  (But, I simply used the OS/X installer helpfully provided on the web site.)  It does *not* come with OS/X by default.  *(I must be workin' too hard ...)*